# Deeplink in ionic3 : don't launch the ionic app with Gmail Link

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ionic3, deep-linking

Codepen Url link with in the href tag click link work is going on.

```
For Example : <a href="com.abc.com://abc.com/testPage">Click</a>
```

But same link is open in chrome it auto adds **https://** protocol which gives this site can't be reached error.

Please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/ standard is designed to solve this issue, but it's only supported on newer versions of Android.

Instead, what you need is hosted deep links. With this set up, your https:// URLs lead to webpages that redirect to your custom URI scheme, which opens the app and deep links your user. You can technically build it yourself, but most developers don't. Services like https://branch.io/  and Firebase Dynamic Links make the process much easier.

Here's a breakdown of the various deep linking options for Ionic: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-deep-link-in-cordova-phonegap-and-ionic/